How to add new table to existing database in kotlin
i need to add a new table to a existing database in kotlin. when i try to add it in the app inspection, database inspection shows the database is closed.enter image description here
here is my code



as I see in your code I did not see any migration code maybe this caused this issue. write migration and maybe it's work.

invalidate and restart will most probably work !!
but still if it does not work for you then
check this THIS out!
